# Why dose Xml Serializer skip certain attributes when serializing and how to avoid it?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, asp.net-core-2.0

I have generated classes with xsd tool from these [XSDs](https://expediaconnectivity.com/apis/availability-rates-restrictions-booking-notification-retrieval-and-confirmation/expedia-quickconnect-avail-rates-api/schemas.html). But after the request to the api, response message says that I did not send attribute flexibleAllocation when I clearly did.

Something must be wrong with the serializer but it doesn't throw any execptions.

This is how I've done ti:

```
public AvailRateUpdateRS AvailRateUpdate()
{
    var refDate = DateTime.Now;
    var requestObject = new AvailRateUpdateRQ()
    {
        Authentication =
            new AvailRateUpdateRQAuthentication()
            {
                username = "SomeUsername",
                password = "SomePassword"
            },

        Hotel = new AvailRateUpdateRQHotel()
        {
            id = 12333123
        },
        Items = new[] {
            new AvailRateUpdateRQAvailRateUpdate
            {

                DateRange = new DateRangeType[]{
                    new DateRangeType{
                        from = refDate,
                        to = refDate
                    }
                },
                RoomType = new RoomTypeType[]{
                    new RoomTypeType{
                        id = "123313",
                        Inventory = new RoomTypeTypeInventory{
                            flexibleAllocation = 3,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var httpRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://services.expediapartnercentral.com/eqc/ar");
    httpRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";

    var requestXml = new XmlDocument();

    using (var requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AvailRateUpdateRQ));
        serializer.Serialize(requestStream, requestObject);
        requestXml.Save(requestStream);
    }

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AvailRateUpdateRS));
        AvailRateUpdateRS deserialized = (AvailRateUpdateRS)serializer.Deserialize(responseStream);
        return deserialized;
    }
}
```

Why does it skip a flexibleAllocation attribute when serializing?

Serialized message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AvailRateUpdateRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.expediaconnect.com/EQC/AR/2011/06">
  <Authentication username="SomeUsername" password="SomePassword" />
  <Hotel id="12333123" />
  <AvailRateUpdate>
    <DateRange from="2018-03-07" to="2018-03-07" />
    <RoomType id="123313">
      <Inventory />
    </RoomType>
  </AvailRateUpdate>
</AvailRateUpdateRQ>
```

BTW The classes (AvailRateUpdateRQ and others) are generated with xsd tool from the xsd files and have not been modified in any other way.

Comment: This question would be clearer if you'd reduce it to a minimal example, at which point you'd be able to include the classes as well, so it's easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because these attributes are optional and if not explicitly **specified** will not be serialized.

**Example:** While this

```
    Inventory = new RoomTypeTypeInventory{
        flexibleAllocation = 3,
    }
```

will be serialized as `<Inventory />`, but adding additional attribute like this

```
    Inventory = new RoomTypeTypeInventory{
        flexibleAllocation = 3,
        flexibleAllocationSpecified = true
    }
```

will result in wanted serialization behaviour `<Inventory flexibleAllocation="3" />`

This applies for the generated classes from Expedia API schema files.